# Take a range of the elements by their indexes from a list

Tags: scala

I have a ziped with indexes list and I'm iterating over it. At each iteration I want to return a range of this list so the first element is the current one and the last element is the element of k indexes further from the current one.

```
 val k = 5
 source.zipWithIndex map { case (x, i) =>
    val items = // take the elements from "x" to source(i + k)
  }
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: not need for zipping... use source.sliding(5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `sliding` should work for you:

```
val source = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
source.sliding(5).toList
```

Output:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6), List(3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```